# Cluster your time-series data

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis, correlation

I have **time-series** data of 12 consumers. The data corresponding to 12 consumers (named as `a ... l`) is
[image]

I want to cluster these consumers so that I may know which of the consumers have utmost similar consumption behavior. Accordingly, I found clustering method [pamk](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fpc/docs/pamk), which automatically calculates the number of clusters in input data.

I assume that I have only two options to calculate the distance between any two time-series, i.e., [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), and [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). I tried both of them and I do get different clusters. Now the question is which one should I rely upon? and why?

When I use `Eulidean` distance I got following clusters:
[image]

and using `DTW` distance I got
[image]

**Conclusion:**
  How will you decide which clustering approach is the best in this case?

Note: I have asked the same question on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181566/60072) also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you cross-posted on SE, which is a better site for such a question.

Comment: How well does your data fit into each clustering result?  Does one give more outliers than the other?  Do the clusters have any physical meaning?

Comment: @Pascal, You are correct that SE is better. But the fact is that form last few days, I observed that I do not get any comment, answer to any of my questions. I find Stack Overflow much more active than Cross-validated.

Comment: But it is not a reason to post an off-topic question here.

Comment: @Pascal, I do not think it is off-topic to stack overflow. On stack overflow there are `2.1k` question related to cluster-analysis while as on cross-validated it is only `1.6k`.

Comment: To me it is, are your not asking about **programming** but about **interpretation**. However, let's see what others think about this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, To me fit means which approach represents data more accurately, and this I am not able to decide. Outliers (`b`, `l`) are equally pointed out by both. To me point of concern is (`i, j`) which are represented accurately by Euclidean and (`f`, `g`) are represented accurately by DTW. Physical meaning is, consumers in same cluster follow similar consumption pattern.

Comment: Can you try cross validating?  Build you clusters using 90% of the real data, and then see how the remaining 10% fit in each case.

Answer (score 0):

1. none of the timeseries above look similar to me. Do you *see* any pattern? Maybe there is no pattern?
2. the clustering visualizations indicate that **there are no clusters**, too. `b` and `l` appear to be the most unusual outliers; followed by `d,e,h`; but there are no clusters there.
3. Also try hierarchical clustering. The **dendrogram** may be more understandable.

But in either way, **there may be no clusters**. You need to be prepared for this outcome, and consider it a valid hypothesis. **Double-check any result**. As you have seen, pam will *always* return a result, and you have absolutely no means to decide which result is more "correct" than the other (most likely, **neither is correct**, and you should *rely* on neither, to answer your question).